# Программно нажать на кнопку при помощи JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как при помощи JavaScript вызвать нажатие кнопки?.
Например, есть кнопка:

```
<input type="submit" id="myButton" onclick="myFunc()" >
```

Мне надо, при помощи JavaScript или jQuery, вызвать ее нажатие. И при этом, чтобы срабатывало событие `onclick`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$('#myButton').click();

Comment: Спасибо, завтра попробую.

Answer (score 2):

метод click() будет работать только в FF

если вам достаточно только вызвать обработчик события myFunc(), не вызывая само событие(и другие обработчики), то стоит использовать что-то вроде

```
if($('#myButton').onclick()!==false) {
    $('#myButton').submit();
}
```